# Is it posible to create css rules with php?

Tags: php, html, css

I have been trying to use the php file as css (i need to generate css with certain logic) but the only info i find is how to use php variables for established css rules. Here is the problem, i need to create a slider (that contain X images using css and php only) so i am using a php file as a css adding the `header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");` at the start, in most examples i find they settle variables inside some php tags and outside the php code they write css code like

```
.Someclass{color:<?php echo $myVarWithTheColor;>;}
```

But i need to actually generate the entire css part with something like

```
<?php for ($i=1; $i < $cantidad; $i++){ echo ".Someclass$i{color:$myVarWithTheColor;>";}
```

Currently the echo does nothing and the file is readed as a css with nothing(if i add css under the php that css is readed properly), i also tried with print and even var_dump with no results

Comment: It will work perfectly fine but you have errors in your code.

Comment: https://rextester.com/LHRSF40194 Check this link, i have edited your code and updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Output is not valid css. Try this:

```
<?php for ($i=1; $i < $cantidad; $i++){ echo ".Someclass$i{color:$myVarWithTheColor;}";} ?>
```

The closing ?> tag is not necessary.

Comment: Yep, i had 2 errors, that one ">" ... and the fact that $cantidad was 0... i swear its always the little things

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :)

```
<style>

    <?php 
    $cantidad = 4;
    $myVarWithTheColor = "red";

    for ($i = 1; $i < $cantidad; $i++) {
      echo ".Someclass" . $i . " {color: " . $myVarWithTheColor . ";}";
    }
    ?>

</style>
```